# Maven proxy: how to add multiple ports?

Tags: maven

How do I add more than one port in Maven's proxy configuration?

```
   <proxy>
      <id>proxyID</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <username>USER</username>
      <password>NONEOFYOURBUSINESS</password>
      <host>host.com</host>
      <port>80</port>
      <nonProxyHosts>*.host.noproxy.com</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
```

Do I need to add another proxy or can I use sth like adding one more `<port>` tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to add another `<proxy>` section to your `<proxies>`. This may mean duplicating some of the configuration between the two proxy sections.

The [Javadoc](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.2.3/maven-settings/apidocs/org/apache/maven/settings/Proxy.html) indicates that the `port` is just an `int` - you can't specify anything more complex that that for a proxy.